# Pandas Update: How to exclude updating of certain values in update df?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update the values in df1 from df2 only for those values in df2 that are not '9999'. How do I do so? Thanks!

I know I can use df1.update(df2) to update the values in df1, but that will update all the values.

**Current State**

```
*df1*

         |Total Assets| AUMs |
Firm 1   | 100        | 300  |
Firm 2   | 200        | 3400 |
Firm 3   | 300        | 800  |
Firm 4   | NaN        | 800  |

*df2*

         |Total Assets| AUMs |
Firm 1   | 200        | 50  |
Firm 2   | 500        | 9999 |
```

**Desired State**

```
*df1*

         |Total Assets| AUMs |
Firm 1   | 200        | 50  |
Firm 2   | 500        | 3400 |
Firm 3   | 300        | 800  |
Firm 4   | NaN        | 800  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `9999` by `NaN` before `update`:

```
df1.update(df2.replace(9999, np.NaN))
```

```
>>> df1
        Total Assets    AUMs
Firm 1         200.0    50.0
Firm 2         500.0  3400.0
Firm 3         300.0   800.0
Firm 4           NaN   800.0
```

OR

If there are multiple values that you want to exclude then use `isin()` and set those values to `NaN` then update:

```
df2.loc[df2['AUMs'].isin([9999]),'AUMs']=float('NaN')
df1.update(df2)
```